# Hazelcast ClassNotFoundException in a Client-Server Deployment

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, hazelcast

Im running hazelcast in client server mode with my Spring Boot App In Kubernetes.

Mostly im using spring cache annotations and hibernate second level caching. But there are few places that im using hazelcast instance to get cache results and put them in programmatically.

MapConfig(note i have an index on the key):

```
val userOrderConfig = MapConfig(Caches.USER_ORDERS)
        userOrderConfig.apply {
            this.evictionConfig = EvictionConfig().setEvictionPolicy(EvictionPolicy.LRU).apply {
                this.maxSizePolicy =MaxSizePolicy.PER_NODE
                this.size = 10000
            }
            this.timeToLiveSeconds = (30*60)
        }
    
        userOrderConfig.addIndexConfig(IndexConfig(IndexType.SORTED, "__key"))
        hzInstance.config.addMapConfig(userOrderConfig)
```

Example Code:

```
        val map = hz.getMap<String, List<UserOrder>>(Caches.USER_ORDERS)
        val key = "${userId}-${otherParameter}"
        val result = map[key]
        
        if (result != null)
            result
        else {
            //some business logic
            map.put(key, result)
            return result
        }
```

And here is the code that clears the cache:

```
    fun clearUserOrderCache(userId: Int){
        val key = "${userId}"
        thread {
            try {
                val map = hz.getMap<String, List<UserOrder>>(Caches.USER_ORDERS)
                map.removeAll(Predicates.like<String, List<UserOrder>>("__key", "$key-%"))
            } catch (ex: Exception) {
                ex.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
    }
```

this code worked fine for the time being. i tested it both pieces of codes. it updates the cache. gets the records properly and clears the cache as it should.

There was no changes to the code that suddenly this line `val result = map[key]` started throwing an exception:
`{"@timestamp":"2023-11-10T14:40:05.295Z","@version":"1","message":"Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.app.models.dtos.UserOrder] with root cause","logger_name":"org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/].[dispatcherServlet]","thread_name":"http-nio-80-exec-143","level":"ERROR","level_value":40000,"stack_trace":"java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.app.models.dtos.UserOrder\n\tat jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)\n\tat jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)\n\tat java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)\n\tat com.hazelcast.internal.nio.ClassLoaderUtil.tryLoadClass(ClassLoaderUtil.java:301)\n\tat com.hazelcast.internal.nio.ClassLoaderUtil.loadClass(ClassLoaderUtil.java:259)\n\tat com.hazelcast.internal.nio.IOUtil$ClassLoaderAwareObjectInputStream.resolveClass(IOUtil.java:894)\n\tat java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:2003)\n\tat java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1870)\n\tat java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2201)\n\tat java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1687)\n\tat java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:489)\n\tat java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:447)\n\tat com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.defaultserializers.JavaDefaultSerializers$JavaSerializer.read(JavaDefaultSerializers.java:92)\n\tat com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.defaultserializers.JavaDefaultSerializers$JavaSerializer.read(JavaDefaultSerializers.java:85)\n\tat com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.StreamSerializerAdapter.read(StreamSerializerAdapter.java:44)\n\tat com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.readObject(AbstractSerializationService.java:352)\n\tat com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.ByteArrayObjectDataInput.readObject(ByteArrayObjectDataInput.java:600)\n\tat com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.defaultserializers.GV9Jm2u7rmsCe65wKzPTw5jtS38n2tVEGi.deserializeEntriesInto(GV9Jm2u7rmsCe65wKzPTw5jtS38n2tVEGi.java:50)\n\tat com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.defaultserializers.GV9Jm2u7rmsCe65wKzPTw5jtS38n2tVEGi.deserializeEntries(GV9Jm2u7rmsCe65wKzPTw5jtS38n2tVEGi.java:43)\n\tat com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.defaultserializers.ArrayListStreamSerializer.read(ArrayListStreamSerializer.java:51)\n\tat com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.defaultserializers.ArrayListStreamSerializer.read(ArrayListStreamSerializer.java:29)\n\tat com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.StreamSerializerAdapter.read(StreamSerializerAdapter.java:44)\n\tat com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.toObject(AbstractSerializationService.java:271)\n\tat com.hazelcast.map.impl.record.Records.tryStoreIntoCache(Records.java:186)\n\tat com.hazelcast.map.impl.record.Records.getValueOrCachedValue(Records.java:153)\n\tat com.hazelcast.map.impl.recordstore.IndexingMutationObserver.removeIndex(IndexingMutationObserver.java:188)\n\tat com.hazelcast.map.impl.recordstore.IndexingMutationObserver.onEvictRecord(IndexingMutationObserver.java:81)\n\tat com.hazelcast.map.impl.recordstore.CompositeMutationObserver.onEvictRecord(CompositeMutationObserver.java:143)\n\tat com.hazelcast.map.impl.recordstore.DefaultRecordStore.evict(DefaultRecordStore.java:561)\n\tat com.hazelcast.map.impl.recordstore.AbstractEvictableRecordStore.evictExpiredEntryAndPublishExpiryEvent(AbstractEvictableRecordStore.java:128)\n\tat com.hazelcast.map.impl.recordstore.AbstractEvictableRecordStore.evictIfExpired(AbstractEvictableRecordStore.java:120)\n\tat com.hazelcast.map.impl.recordstore.DefaultRecordStore.getRecordOrNull(DefaultRecordStore.java:1249)\n\tat com.hazelcast.map.impl.recordstore.DefaultRecordStore.get(DefaultRecordStore.java:679)\n\tat com.hazelcast.map.impl.recordstore.RecordStore.get(RecordStore.java:173)\n\tat com.hazelcast.map.impl.operation.GetOperation.runInternal(GetOperation.java:50)\n\tat com.hazelcast.map.impl.operation.MapOperation.run(MapOperation.java:153)\n\tat com.hazelcast.map.impl.operation.MapOperation.call(MapOperation.java:173)\n\tat com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.call(OperationRunnerImpl.java:283)\n\tat com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.run(OperationRunnerImpl.java:258)\n\tat com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.run(OperationRunnerImpl.java:219)\n\tat com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationExecutorImpl.run(OperationExecutorImpl.java:411)\n\tat com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationExecutorImpl.runOrExecute(OperationExecutorImpl.java:438)\n\tat com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.Invocation.doInvokeLocal(Invocation.java:601)\n\tat com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.Invocation.doInvoke(Invocation.java:580)\n\tat com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.Invocation.invoke0(Invocation.java:541)\n\tat com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:241)\n\tat com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.InvocationBuilderImpl.invoke(InvocationBuilderImpl.java:61)\n\tat com.hazelcast.client.impl.protocol.task.AbstractPartitionMessageTask.processInternal(AbstractPartitionMessageTask.java:51)\n\tat com.hazelcast.client.impl.protocol.task.AbstractAsyncMessageTask.processMessage(AbstractAsyncMessageTask.java:71)\n\tat com.hazelcast.client.impl.protocol.task.AbstractMessageTask.initializeAndProcessMessage(AbstractMessageTask.java:153)\n\tat com.hazelcast.client.impl.protocol.task.AbstractMessageTask.run(AbstractMessageTask.java:116)\n\tat com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.run(OperationRunnerImpl.java:198)\n\tat com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationThread.process(OperationThread.java:207)\n\tat com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationThread.process(OperationThread.java:141)\n\tat com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationThread.executeRun(OperationThread.java:123)\n\tat com.hazelcast.internal.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.run(HazelcastManagedThread.java:102)\n"}`

So as far as i looked at the exception it seems to me, and i might be wrong here, that at some point when GetOperation happens on hazelcast server. it checks if the record is expired and it tries to evict record and simultaneously remove an index on it. and somewhere during an index removal process it tries to deserialize the values and since none of my classes are on hazelcast server classpath error happens. Which yes i could solve by either removing an index(dont really need it), putting my classes on the classpath, or providing the classes from the config.

But i just want to know where the inconsistency comes from. And what triggers this very specific scenario.

Answer (score 1):

When you call map.addIndex you can add an index for either the **key**, the **value** ,or for **both**. For example, the following code adds indices for two fields of the value object

```java
IMap<String, Employee> map = instance.getMap("employees");
map.addIndex(IndexType.SORTED, "age");
map.addIndex(IndexType.HASH, "active");
```

In your example you are adding an index for the **key**.

When accessing an object, Hazelcast first checks if the entry has expired.
If it has, HZ **removes** the object from **all** indices and return **null** to the user

For index removal, the **index registry** will attempt to deserialize **both** key and value and extract the attribute from the corresponding location. It then instructs all indices to remove this combination of **attribute plus key**.

The related code is as below. See https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/blob/master/hazelcast/src/main/java/com/hazelcast/map/impl/recordstore/IndexingMutationObserver.java#L176

```java
private void removeIndex(Data dataKey, Record record,
                         Index.OperationSource operationSource) {
  IndexRegistry indexRegistry = mapContainer.getOrCreateIndexRegistry(partitionId);
  if (!indexRegistry.haveAtLeastOneIndex()) {
    return;
  }
  indexRegistry.removeEntry(
    toBackingKeyFormat(dataKey),  
    getValueOrCachedValue(record, ss), //<--- Here is the problem
    operationSource);
}
```

**getValueOrCachedValue()** attempts to deserialize the record, which is the value object, but it fails because the value object's class is not in the classpath. This is the cause of the exception.

In summary, index removal begins by deserializing the value object and attempting to extract the attribute value. Even though there is only one index for the key in this instance, the Hazelcast code is written in a generic manner to accommodate various types of indices.

This is my understanding of the situation. I hope it helps

---

Regarding the comment why it happens occasionally. Here is the related code in AbstractEvictableRecordStore.java

```java
@Override
public boolean evictIfExpired(Data key, long now, boolean backup) {
  ExpiryReason expiryReason = hasExpired(key, now, backup);
  if (expiryReason == NOT_EXPIRED) {
    return false;
  }
  evictExpiredEntryAndPublishExpiryEvent(key, expiryReason, backup);
  return true;
}
```

So entries are only removed from the index when they expire. This is why exception happens occasionally.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. Thats pretty much what i figured out too. The thing i want to know is why does it occur occasionally. Most of the times it works fine.

Comment: @jetro157 please see my updated answer

Comment: okay that makes sense but only partially. I also saw that part of the code and its my understanding that this only happens when u try to access the record from the map and it checks if it has expired(just in case). It doesnt happen when hazelcast server removes the record on its own when it expires.  Also an interesting point is that there was a set of users for whom the problem started happening until i restarted the whole cluster. WHICH SHOULD MEAN that the records were already expired and yet hazelcast cluster failed to remove them on its own. Do you have any idea why would that happen?